# Adb push Chinese file name with space to Android sdcard with nodejs

Tags: android, node.js, adb, filenames, chinese-locale

I can push file to Android sdcard with this command:

```
adb push /path/to/file/test.mp3 /sdcard/Music
```

But this time, my filename contains space and Chinese character:

```
adb push /path/to/file/猜猜 猜猜.mp3 /sdcard/Music
```

I try to create a nodjs script to automate the adb push, but I am unsure how to handle filename with space and Chinese characters.

Full code: https://github.com/kenpeter/adb_push_music

Answer (score 0):

You need add a `\` to add special symbol.

```
adb push /path/to/file/猜猜\ 猜猜.mp3 /sdcard/Music
```

Answer (score 0):

[Code has been updated](https://github.com/kenpeter/adb_push_music/blob/master/adb_push_music.js).

Based on @Yat3s suggestion, I did something like `replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%'":*?<>{}\ ]/g, "_")` to the file name.